# Which FREE ebook readers for Windows allow two-column view and left justification?

Tags: epub-reader

Which ebook readers for Windows allow two-column view and left justification?
Calibre and Sumantra allow two-column view but not left justification.
I find left-justified text faster to read. This is in accordance to typographer's opinion.

Comment: For Calibre, you can try using a custom stylesheet in Settings->User Stylesheet.

Comment: @beaker   I tried, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueFire Reader displays the text in multiple columns, and you can set the alignment to left or justified. The alignment setting shows up when you check the advanced settings box in the settings dialog (the gear icon in the toolbar).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Do you know any free reader that does the trick?

Comment: The Bluefire Reader app itself is free. You can download it from here: http://www.bluefirereader.com/bluefire-reader.html. They have a paid service for retailers that lets them add their branding to the reader, but for regular users the app is free.